# Wordpress wp_set_object_terms is not working for custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

Hi guys i am trying to add post in WordPress. I used CPT UI to created/register custom post type and custom taxonomies. I used the code below to add my post.

```
     $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $description,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'questions',
     );
     $post_id =  wp_insert_post($post);
     $check_if_save = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id , array(10,11 ), 'question-category' );
```

But when this code executed `$check_if_save->get_error_message()` always returns an `Invalid Taxonomy`. I also check the `get_taxonomies()` but my custom taxonomy is not included. I also register taxonomy manually and follow  this [link](http://biostall.com/why-a-custom-taxonomy-might-not-be-returned-in-wordpress/comment-page-1#comment-11698) as a solution. But i doesn't work for me.

Any ideas why this happen?

Comment: Need to register the taxonomy. CPT ui doesn't registering the taxonomy i guess

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're creating your taxonomies before the custom post type they belong to.